# objective-c iphone programming : background task every 10 minutes

Tags: iphone, methods, background, task

i want my application to execute a specific method each 10 minutes while in background
It is possible ? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by background?? is it background thread or when application is in background..?????

Comment: when i leave the app. it enter the method every 10 minutes

Comment: your reply is not still clear. If it is firing a method for every 10 mins then you can use the method  `[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60*10 target:self selector:@selector(yourMethod:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];`

Comment: ok Ill be clear, when you leave the app it enter the method DidEnterBackground: i wanna know if the app can execute a method each 10 minutes from there.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question correctly... do you mean after the user hits the Home button?

If so,  then I believe it is not possible to do what you want to do.

From apple docs the iOS application can become active in the background to do one or more of the following:

1. Task completion: when the app starts a task and the user hit the home button the app can ask to continue doing the task for a limited time in the background then enters the suspended state
2. Location: the app becomes active for limited time when location change is triggered.
3. For playing audio
4. VOIP

Have a look at the multitasking guidelines docs.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

```
minutesTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60*10 target:self selector:@selector(update) userInfo:NULL repeats:YES];
```

Comment: i wanna execute a timer in background

Comment: Seriously, no-one can give an answer to this?
Im having the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ([countTimer isValid]==NO)
{
    countTimer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:600 target:self selector:@selector(YourMethod) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```